# Парсинг изображений с площадки Розетка

Tags: json, парсер, изображения

Все доброго времени суток. Поделитесь как правильно спарсить все картинки с товара на Розетке.
Первая картинка парситься нормально, а все последующие как я понял лежат в таком формате:

```
{&q;url&q;:&q;https://i2.rozetka.ua/goods/14371712/128962993_images_14371712976.jpg&q;,&q;width&q;:52,&q;height&q;:100},&q;mobile_large&q;:{&q;url&q;:&q;https://i1.rozetka.ua/goods/14371712/128962993_images_14371712955.jpg&q;,&q;width&q;:105,&q;height&q;:200},&q;original&q;:
```

Как их правильно спарсить. Может у у кого то есть работающий прием

Answer (score 0):

Здесь `&q;` это двойные кавычки `"` - просто замените их `response.replace(/&q;/g, '"')`, а затем примените `JSON.parse` - на выходе готовая сущность, у которой вам нужно взять поле `url`

```js
var tmp = JSON.parse(response.replace(/&q;/g, '"'));
var imageUrl = tmp.url;
```

`colsole.log(tmp)` выдаст что-то такое

```
{original: {…}, mobile_large: {…}}
original: {url: "https://-------/goods/14371712/128962993_images_14371712976.jpg", width: 52, height: 100}
mobile_large: {url: "https://--------/goods/14371712/128962993_images_14371712955.jpg", width: 105, height: 200}
__proto__: Object
```

Точнее, как выдаст - выдал бы, если бы ваш пример не содержал битый json. Такое ощущение что это не весь текст. Но на случай такой можно вытащить все `url` из того что есть:

```
response.replace(/&q;/g, '"').match(/"url":"[^",}]+/g)
```

Результат будет массив ссылок:

```
0: ""url":"https://---------/goods/14371712/128962993_images_14371712976.jpg"
1: ""url":"https://---------/goods/14371712/128962993_images_14371712955.jpg"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

а дальше в каждом элементе выдрать адрес с помощью `match(/"url":"([^",}]+)/)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It work me well.

```
$string = str_replace(["&q;"], '"', $string);
$string = str_replace(["&a;"], "&", $string);
$string = str_replace(["G.https"], "https", $string);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // а ещё здесь принято общаться на русском языке.